# Why does my Angular app display the path of my html-file and not its contents?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am starting with Angular. I am creating a very simple App, that uses two components. A default app component and a second component that is used in the html-file of the app component.

However, when running the app (see files below for the relevant files), I get the following output:

> ### App component
>
> ./server.component.html

Instead of what is actually in the html-file, in my case:

> ### App component
>
> The server component

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

**Here is my Module:** (app.module.ts)

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ServerComponent } from './server/server.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ServerComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**The html-file of my main component** (app.component.html)

```
<p>App Coponent</p>
<hr>
<app-server></app-server>
```

**The server component** (server/server.component.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-server',
    template: './server.component.html'
})
export class ServerComponent {

}
```

and, finally, **the html-file of the server component** (server/server.component.html)

```
<p>The server component</p>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-server',
    template: './server.component.html'
})
```

to

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-server',
    templateUrl: './server.component.html'
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been staring at the code for a long time. This does the trick!